# this.props out of date inside componentDidUpdate() using Higher Order Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have a higher order component which sets some values and then passes those as props to a wrappedComponent, however within that wrapped component when I access "this.props" from componentDidMount() the values are blank. If I place logs "this.props" from the render method in the wrappedComponent however I get the desired results, though i assume this is because of a re-render. What am i doing wrong here?

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// eslint-disable-next-line
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import BlogSummaryContainer from './utility/BlogSummaryContainer'
import BlogPost from './utility/BlogPost'
import EditableBlogPost from './utility/EditableBlogPost'

function withBlogPostData (WrappedComponent) {
  return class BlogPostContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
      super()
      this.state = { title: '', content: '', catchPhrase: '' }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      fetch(`/api/posts/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(res => {
          return res.json()
        })
        .then(blogPost => {
         // this setState doesnt reach the wrappedComponent in time even if i dont do a fetch and simply hard code a value, whats going on?
          this.setState({
            title: blogPost.title,
            content: blogPost.content,
            catchPhrase: blogPost.catchPhrase
          })
        })
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          id={this.props.match.params.id}
          title={this.state.title}
          content={this.state.content}
          catchPhrase={this.state.catchPhrase}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  ... other code

  render () {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${this.props.match.url}`}
          render={() => {
            return <BlogSummaryContainer posts={this.state.blogPosts} />
          }}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${this.props.match.url}/:id`}
          component={withBlogPostData(BlogPost)}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${this.props.match.url}/:id/edit`}
          component={withBlogPostData(EditableBlogPost)}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${this.props.match.url}/new/post`}
          render={() => {
            return <EditableBlogPost isNew />
          }}
        />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

EditableBlogPost.js

```
  componentDidMount (props) {
    const { title, catchPhrase, content } = this.props
    console.log('this.props', this.props) // this.props = {title: "", content: "", ... }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just an asynchronous problem - when your HOC mounts it is calling `fetch()` which isn't resolved instantly so that is why on the first render `this.state.x` are their initial empty values.

When the Promise is resolved, the values are set and the subsequent `render` will have the expected values.

You could conditionally render to avoid rendering the wrapped component until the `fetch()` has resolved:

```
render () {
  if(this.state.title.length === 0) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; //or some nice <Loading> component
  }

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      id={this.props.match.params.id}
      title={this.state.title}
      content={this.state.content}
      catchPhrase={this.state.catchPhrase}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not the case, even without the fetch, simply hardcoding the values doesn't work either. Only reason I included the example as is was because otherwise i would have been told to just do the variable setup in the constructor.

Comment: when you say you hardcode the values, do you mean in the `constructor()` or in a `setState()` call?

Comment: `componentDidMount () {
        this.setState({
          title: 'hello world'
        })
    }`
This gives the same result as with the fetch. ie:  title: "", content: "", catchPhrase: ""}

Comment: `setState()` also doesn't update state instantly. Try putting values on `this.state = {}` in the `constructor()` and I suspect that may work

Comment: I need to make a fetch to the backend though. which from my understanding is not something that you do in the constructor

Comment: using componentWillMount() (not componentDidMount) I'm able to setState({title: 'hello world'}), though im still unable to have it work with the fetch(). My understanding was that componentDidMount was for async actions, and therefore should work for this?

Comment: It will work, but the component has mounted so that means the wrapped component has rendered BUT your fetch hasn't resolved yet

Comment: You are correct, so it seems its because componentDidMount in the wrappedComponent is called too early and since its only called twice it wont have the correct results. It works with the conditional you provided above. Thank you!

Comment: is there a more elegant way of doing this though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168013/discussion-between-tony-and-matt-pengelly).

Comment: The solution pointed out by Tony was in fact the fix to the problem.